# JSON: Object or Array

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I have WEB API which returns me some information about posts
if post has images:

```
"thumbnail_images":{"small":{"url":"http:....png","width":211,"height":150},"medium":...
```

But if post hasn't images:

```
"thumbnail_images":[]
```

I create `public ThumbnailImages thumbnail_images { get; set; }`
But when post hasn't images i have to create `public List<ThumbnailImages> thumbnail_images { get; set; }`

What should i do?

Comment: Always create the list if it is possible there is a collection. If its one object, its a one-element list. No problems there.

Comment: Can you fix the API to be consistent?

Comment: SLaks, i can't do this.
BradleyDotNET, It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok. I did so
Replace("\"thumbnail_images\":[]", "\"thumbnail_images\":{\"small\":{\"url\":\"null\"}}");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I did so Replace("\"thumbnail_images\":[]", "\"thumbnail_images\":{\"small\":{\"url\":\"null\"}}");